# Why won't jQuery accept this string?

Tags: jquery

When I run this function:

```
onUnCheck: function(el) {
var thenames = "icon-"+el.find("label:first").text().replace(/ /g,'').toLowerCase();        
alert(thenames);            
$("'."+thenames+"'").hide("fast");
}
```

I generate a string. I can see in the alert() that it is indeed the correct string. Example:

```
icon-jira
```

But when I pass the string in as a jQuery selector it does not work.

I know the function's logic is sound because pasting in the result of my alert() makes it work.

Why won't jQuery accept my string?

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.'+thenames).hide("fast");
```

This will look for ".icon-jira."  You were looking for "'.icon-jira'" which adds the quotes to the selector.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have an extra set of single quotes (`''`).  Try this:

```
onUnCheck: function(el) {
  var thenames = "icon-"+el.find("label:first").text().replace(/\s/g,'').toLowerCase();        
  alert(thenames);            
  $("."+thenames).hide("fast");
}
```

Also, consider using `/\s/g` instead of `/ /g` -- `/\s/g` is a little less error prone and a bit more readable.

Comment: Thanks for that extra tip.  If I may ask one more silly question:  What if I wanted to strip out:  periods, commas, (), /,\, and _  how would I add that to this replace?

Comment: To get remove of those character specifically you can use `.replace(/[.,()/\\_]/g, "")`.  Note that inside a regex character set only `^`, `-`, `]`, and ` \ ` have to be escaped.  Another option is get remove characters that are *not* alphanumeric.  In that case you can use `.replace(/[^\a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "")`, though keep in mind that this regex also removes accented characters.